# Conditional sub-setting or nulling

Tags: r, null, subset, tidyr

I have to include participants into a dataframe(or existing data frame) if they have higher score in invalid conditions relative to valid conditions. But I have two times of (T1-T3) data.

I have tried this one: `data_new <- subset(data_raw, T1_invalid > T1_valid & T3_invalid > T3_valid)`

However, it did not work because, for instance, some participants may have higher invalid score in just one time (T1), not in the second time (T3), or vice versa.

For example, a person can have higher invalid in one of the times, let's say T1_invalid > T1_valid. This should be included to the new data frame, it is okay. But, T3_invalid - T3_valid should be excluded because the invalid score is not higher than the valid score. But when you use AND operator, it excludes the person because, they have to have higher invalid scores in both T1 and T3. So, we over exclude in that case.

When you use OR operator it is the same. For example, a person has a higher score in T1_invalid > T1_valid, but not in the T3_invalid - T3_valid. Then, since one of the conditions is okay, it includes the person, but this person failed at T3. So, we should exclude T3_invalid - valid scores.

So basically, I was looking for something can check them separately. Then, I decided to make it null one by one like this:

```
data_raw[data_raw$T1_invalid < data_raw$T1_valid, c("T1_invalid", "T1_valid")] <- NA
data_raw[data_raw$T3_invalid < data_raw$T3_valid, c("T3_invalid", "T3_valid")] <- NA
```

However, it did not let me do this because I use the variables two times, for the condition part (>) and for make it null.

Does anyone have any idea? By the way they have to be in the same data frame for using in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Here I provide a normal `data.table` solution. You can have a try.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data_raw)

data_raw[, T1_invalid := ifelse(T1_invalid < T1_valid,NA,T1_invalid)]
data_raw[, T1_valid := ifelse(T1_invalid < T1_valid,NA,T1_valid)]

data_raw[, T3_invalid := ifelse(T3_invalid < T3_valid,NA,T3_valid)]
data_raw[, T3_valid := ifelse(T3_invalid < T3_valid,NA,T3_valid)]
```